Bitcoin amount not showing on Phantom in my new Android phone
In my Phantom wallet I have SOL and BTC, I tried installing Phantom app on my new mobile and import my wallet to it but it only imports SOL and not BTC even though I enabled the BTC network option, it only imports my amount of SOL and not my BTC amount which is weird!
I have the latest Phantom app on my Android, both my phones are Android.
